# How to define my own numbering list?

Tags: lists, enumerate

I want to define a list which have some part of contents.

Just like the iamge show

first part: `number`

second part: `[Q:]`

third part: `some text`

fourth parth: `[A:]`

fifth part: `long text`

I can do it with tabular, but I think there is better way to do it, so anyone can help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are right, there are simpler ways. Here is one without loading any packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{itemize}
\item[Q:] XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX
 XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX
\item[A:]  XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX
\end{itemize}
\item \begin{itemize}
\item[Q:] XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX
 XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX
\item[A:]  XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]